# nestjs with axios, handling connect ENETUNREACH

Tags: axios, nestjs

I am pretty new to nestjs.

I am building an application, which gets images from other devices. However, the internet connection is unstable for the devices. Sometimes, it produces errors like,

[Nest] 30899  - 02/04/2022, 8:09:25 PM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] connect ENETUNREACH 0.0.0.0:11
Error: connect ENETUNREACH 0.0.0.0:11

When the error occurs, the below lines of the Axios function is not executed, which I want to avoid.

Thus, I want to know how to catch this error to handle(try catch block do not work for this case).

Here is my code just in case.

```
try {
        const response: AxiosResponse = await this.httpService.axiosRef({
          url: `http://${cam.publicIP}:${cam.webPort}/capture`,
          method: 'GET',
          responseType: 'arraybuffer',
          timeout: 1500,
        })
        const buffer = Buffer.from(response.data, "utf-8");
        const resized = await sharp(buffer).extract({
          left: 100,
          top: 0,
          width: 600,
          height: 600,
        }).resize().toBuffer();
        const imageUrl = await this.storageService.upload('images', {
          name: imageName,
          buffer: resized
        });
        console.log(imageUrl);

        snapshot.imageUrl = imageUrl;
        // await snapshot.save();
        console.log(snapshot.id);


      } catch (error) {
        this.logger.debug(error);
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`0.0.0.0` is not a valid IP address. Historically, it has been used to specify all local IP addresses when binding to a local port for accepting incoming connections. Some OS/clients/stacks have extended it to mean the local host, but you should not expect this to always work. Use `127.0.0.1` if you want to connect to the localhost.

There is no reason that your code won't catch this error if it is thrown by `axios`. Check where the error is thrown - it is probably thrown somewhere else.

Comment: Actually, 0.0.0.0 is just a boilerplate for hiding the public IP address. I just find out the sync with my container caused this error. As you said there is no reason for a try-catch block not to catch the error. Anyway, thanks for you help :)